# Rsync: rsync not move some files

Tags: rsync

This is my `rsync` command:

```
rsync -av --progress \
  --exclude=".*" \
  --exclude="target/*" \
  --exclude="src/main/docker" \
  --exclude="src/test" \
  ~/projects/workarea/arxius-linia/backend/ \
  ~/projects/workarea/arxius-linia/gene/backend/
```

Nevertheless, it seems something is not synchronized since:

```
$ diff -qr --exclude=.git --exclude=".*" \
  ~/projects/workarea/arxius-linia/backend \
  ~/projects/workarea/arxius-linia/gene/backend
```

`diff` command is getting me some diffs:

```
Only in /home/jeusdi/projects/workarea/arxius-linia/gene/backend/src/main/java/net/gencat/clt/arxius/backend/constants: BookConstants.java
Only in /home/jeusdi/projects/workarea/arxius-linia/gene/backend/src/main/java/net/gencat/clt/arxius/backend/constants: ParticipateConstants.java
Only in /home/jeusdi/projects/workarea/arxius-linia/gene/backend/src/main/java/net/gencat/clt/arxius/backend/controller: BookDocumentationController.java
Only in /home/jeusdi/projects/workarea/arxius-linia/gene/backend/src/main/java/net/gencat/clt/arxius/backend/controller/impl: BookDocumentationControllerImpl.java
Only in /home/jeusdi/projects/workarea/arxius-linia/gene/backend/src/main/java/net/gencat/clt/arxius/backend/controller/impl: ParticipateControllerImpl.java
Only in /home/jeusdi/projects/workarea/arxius-linia/gene/backend/src/main/java/net/gencat/clt/arxius/backend/controller: ParticipateController.java
Only in /home/jeusdi/projects/workarea/arxius-linia/gene/backend/src/main/java/net/gencat/clt/arxius/backend/dao: BookDocDAO.java
Only in /home/jeusdi/projects/workarea/arxius-linia/gene/backend/src/main/java/net/gencat/clt/arxius/backend/dao: BookDocumentationRepository.java
Only in /home/jeusdi/projects/workarea/arxius-linia/gene/backend/src/main/java/net/gencat/clt/arxius/backend/dao: ParticipateDAO.java
Only in /home/jeusdi/projects/workarea/arxius-linia/gene/backend/src/main/java/net/gencat/clt/arxius/backend/dao: ParticipateRepository.java
Only in /home/jeusdi/projects/workarea/arxius-linia/gene/backend/src/main/java/net/gencat/clt/arxius/backend/dao: StatisticsDAO.java
Only in /home/jeusdi/projects/workarea/arxius-linia/gene/backend/src/main/java/net/gencat/clt/arxius/backend/domain: BookDocumentationDomainModel.java
Only in /home/jeusdi/projects/workarea/arxius-linia/gene/backend/src/main/java/net/gencat/clt/arxius/backend/domain: BookUnitDomainModel.java
Only in /home/jeusdi/projects/workarea/arxius-linia/gene/backend/src/main/java/net/gencat/clt/arxius/backend/domain/form: BookDocumentationFormModel.java
Only in /home/jeusdi/projects/workarea/arxius-linia/gene/backend/src/main/java/net/gencat/clt/arxius/backend/domain/form: ParticipateFormModel.java
Only in /home/jeusdi/projects/workarea/arxius-linia/gene/backend/src/main/java/net/gencat/clt/arxius/backend/domain: ParticipateDomainModel.java
Only in /home/jeusdi/projects/workarea/arxius-linia/gene/backend/src/main/java/net/gencat/clt/arxius/backend/service: BookDocumentationService.java
Only in /home/jeusdi/projects/workarea/arxius-linia/gene/backend/src/main/java/net/gencat/clt/arxius/backend/service: ParticipateService.java
Only in /home/jeusdi/projects/workarea/arxius-linia/gene/backend/src/main/resources/mailTemplates: MailParticipateArchive.ftlh
Only in /home/jeusdi/projects/workarea/arxius-linia/gene/backend/src/main/resources/mailTemplates: MailParticipateValidation.ftlh
Only in /home/jeusdi/projects/workarea/arxius-linia/gene/backend/src/main/resources/mailTemplates: SubjectParticipateArchive.ftlh
Only in /home/jeusdi/projects/workarea/arxius-linia/gene/backend/src/main/resources/mailTemplates: SubjectParticipateValidation.ftlh
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The files that you list as `Only in ...` are all located under the target directory.  What this means is that those files were there before you ran the `rsync` command.

If you want to remove those files from the target directory, you may run the `rsync` command with its `--delete` option.  Doing so would delete all files in the target directory hierarchy not present in the source directory hierarchy.  You may also want to investigate using the `--delete-excluded` option if you need to delete files at the target that match any of your exclusion patterns.

Consider testing this on a copy of the data first or at least with the `--dry-run` option (or `-n`) to see what files `rsync` would remove, and always take frequent backups.

Comment: Is there any option in order to keep some directories that only exists in target but doesn't exist in src?

Comment: @Jordi There is no way to tell `rsync` to selectively delete files and directories from the target hierarchy when they don't exist at the source.  You either delete all that don't exist, or you leave them.  If the files fulfill some general criteria (like having a particular filename suffix), it would be easy to go through and delete them with `find` afterward.  You may want to ask a separate question about this if you can't find an existing query that deals with it.

Comment: `--exclude` will do that for you @Jordi. (Documentation - `man rsync` - says, "_Files that are excluded from the transfer are also excluded from being deleted unless you use the `--delete-excluded` option or mark the rules as only matching on the sending side_")

Comment: @roaima In the user's example, deleting those Java files would be possible with `--delete`. To keep some of them, you could use `--exclude` to exclude a parent directory to avoid deleting them from that directory, for example.  But that would also skip copying all other files of that directory. In the end, getting a more fine-grained control means having to use `--exclude` for individual files, which may be awkward.

Comment: Exactly. Perhaps `--exclude-from` rather than `--exclude`, but the principle is the same: exclusion paths apply on both sides

Comment: @roaima Point taken. I won't put this into my answer as it's a follow-up topic. I'll let it stay in the comments.

Comment: @Jordi See discussion above. If you have a specific question regarding this follow-up topic, feel free to ask a new question if you can't find an existing query on the site about it.